# Regex for the repeated pattern

Tags: python, regex

Can you please get me python regex that can match

```
9am, 5pm, 4:30am, 3am
```

Simply saying - it has the list of times in csv format

I know the pattern for time, here it is:

```
 '^(\\d{1,2}|\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})(am|pm)$'
```

Comment: I need regex for the text given. The pattern I provided is only for "9am", or "10:30pm", but not for csv of times like "9am, 3:30pm"

Comment: https://txt2re.com/index-python.php3?s=4:30am,%209am&2&10&6

Answer (score 1):

`^(\d+(:\d+)?(am|pm)(, |$))+` will work for you.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/8F285c/3)

Comment: It matches even for any additional text added at the end of it

Comment: @user2349115 - What kind of text?.  Can you give me the input(s)?

Comment: "9am, 5pm, 4:30am, 3amsdfkldnfknskflksd hello" - text

Comment: @user2349115 - It matches only the `9am, 5pm, 4:30am, ` part (add it in regex101 and check) :)

Comment: Yeah, it is working in that site, I tested in python, but may be wrongly. Thanks :)

Comment: @user2349115 - Not an expert in *python*, but I think it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a regex `X` and you want a list of them separated by comma and (optional) spaces, it's a simple matter to do:

```
^X(,\s*X)*$
```

The `X` is, of course, your current search pattern sans anchors though you could adapt that to  be shorter as well. To my mind, a better pattern for the times would be:

```
\d{1,2}(:\d{2})?[ap]m
```

meaning that the full pattern for what you want would be:

```
^\d{1,2}(:\d{2})?[ap]m(,\s*\d{1,2}(:\d{2})?[ap]m)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to get all the matches for a given regex

```
>>> str = "hello world 9am, 5pm, 4:30am, 3am hai"
>>> re.findall(r'\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})?(?:am|pm)', str)
['9am', '5pm', '4:30am', '3am']
```

---

**What it does?**

- `\d{1,2}` Matches one or two digit
- `(?::\d{1,2})` Matches `:` followed by one ore 2 digits. The `?:` is to prevent regex from capturing the group. 
  The `?` at the end makes this part optional.
- `(?:am|pm)` Match `am` or `pm`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
tstr = '9am, 5pm, 4:30am, 3amsdfkldnfknskflksd hello'
print(re.findall(r'\b\d+(?::\d+)?(?:am|pm)', tstr))
```

The output:

```
['9am', '5pm', '4:30am', '3am']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
((?:\d?\d(?:\:?\d\d?)?(?:am|pm)\,?\s?)+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/nkcWt5/1